# ParametricNDSolve problem

Tags: parametric-functions

when i use ParametricNDSolve, the output is not a explicit function, for example:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];
The output is ->   {y -> ParametricFunction[ <> ]}
```

this output just says that y is a parametric function, but i  need to know explicit form of y. how can i obtain y function in terms of t and a?

Comment: Nope, `ParametricNDSolve[]` implements numerical (not symbolical) methods

Comment: `DSolve` solves this simple ODE symbolically.  It will solve many ODEs, but it cannot solve all ODEs.

Answer (score 3):

One interpretation of the question is how to construct a solution that is explicitly a function the independent variable and the parameters as arguments.  Here is one way:

```
solFN = Block[{y, a}, 
  Function @@ 
    {{t, a}, ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}][a][t]}
  ]
(*  Function[{t, a}, ParametricFunction[ <> ][a][t]]  *)

solPFN[1, 3]
(*  20.0855  *)
```

The use of `Block` can be omitted in certain cases.  What it does is temporarily clear `y`, `a`, and `t` of any values they have, so that the solution is computed in terms of the symbols.  Inside `Function` the symbols are localized.

Another way to interpret the question is how to find an explicit **symbolic** solution.  For that, one needs [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DSolve.html) or `DSolveValue`:

```
solFN = Block[{y, a, t},
         Function @@ {{t, a}, DSolveValue[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y[t], t]}
         ]
(*  Function[{t, a}, E^(a t)]  *)

solFN[t, 3]
(*  E^(3 t)  *)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be much easier to just do `solution = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, 
  y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]`? Then `solution[0.5]` gets the solution as an interpolating function for e.g. `a=0.5` and `solution[0.5][5]` evaluates this for `t=5`...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I assumed the OP realized this but wanted the solution as an explicit function of two arguments, `t` and `a` (where I interpreted "explicit" as above). I don't know why it would be desired in this form.  Perhaps it's being passed to another function that requires it.  E.g. `Apply` or `MapThread`.  It might seem simpler to use `solPFN = psol[#2][#1] &`. where `psol` is the output of `ParametricNDSolveValue`, but I thought using symbols `t` and `a` for the parameters would make it clearer to OP what they represent.

Comment: I might point out that by default `ParameterNDSolve` will return a `ParametricFunction` that caches its solutions, so that for a given `a`, the differential equation is integrated only once.  (This is true for the solution in my answer.)

Comment: OK. I understand, but I think it would make sense to point out that what is returned can actually be used in a straightforward way. I didn't understand the OPs question like that, but the question isn't exactly clear :-).

Comment: @AlbertRetey Maybe the OP will clarify and I can update.  Or maybe I've totally missed the point and will delete.